# Create Draggable div based off jQuery Semi Transparent Drag and Drop visual

Tags: jquery

I have a simple DIV

```
 <div class="draggable">some text</div>
```

I'm dragging around that I'm using the "Ghost" or "Semi Transparent Clone" visual affect using the jQuery UI as listed at: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#visual-feedback

What I am trying to do is create a new draggable DIV at the location of the "Ghost" div after its been dropped.

The code I attempted (which shows the "Ghost/Semi-Transparent") is..

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    opacity: 0.7, helper: "clone",
 stop: function() {
     alert($(this).offset().top);
  }
});
```

current code demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y49bg4pf/

I tried setting up an Alert just to test the offset of the ghost object, but of course its only showing me the offset of the original and not the ghost.  I'm assuming once I can figure this part out, then I should be able to just create a new DIV and assign it the class "draggable" to do this all over again with the newly created DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've organized your code properly (separated the CSS from the markup) and I've added a wrapper div called `container`. You can access the offset values you're after through the `ui.offset` but you need to send it as param on your `stop` function.

Let me know if this is the desired behaviour. Dragging from the original will **create** a new element which is draggable, but does not continue creating new elements on drag.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    opacity: 0.7,
    helper: "clone",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      var newEl = $(this).clone();
      newEl.css("top", ui.offset.top);
      newEl.css("left", ui.offset.left);
      $('#container').append(newEl);
      $(".draggable").draggable();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#container{
  position: relative;
}
.draggable{
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: maroon;
  color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="container">
<div class="draggable">some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome code thanks for the help.  Looks like I was close to the answer with getting the offset's, however I didn't know about the parameters to pass  for the stop function (e,ui) i should of read the API apparently, lol.  Thank you very much for showing me also the completed part of created the new div from the "ghost"

Comment: actually I found a huge bug with this code.  It does the offset to the complete page and not the offset in regards to the container itself.  So if you have the "container" inside of another DIV that has say maybe a padding of 50px then where it drops isn't correct. Anyway you can update your code for this bug please? https://jsfiddle.net/y49bg4pf/1/

Comment: I'll reply with a comment since this is beyond the original question, but despite it's not _clean_, here's a way you can take that into account. Since you're positioning elements based on top and left, you need to substract the value of the padding top and left respectively of your #outer div. https://jsfiddle.net/y49bg4pf/4/